# Join two tables and return the entire result using EF 4 and RIA services

Tags: silverlight, entity-framework-4, ria, wcf-ria-services

I'm building a Silverlight application using RIA services and the entity framework 4.0.  I have two tables in my SQL database that I would like to join and return as a single result.  First, my two tables:

---

```
Room:
id
RoomName
BuildingId
```

---

```
Building:
id
BuildingName
```

My Default domain service generated a default GetRooms method:

```
Public Function GetRooms() As IQueryable(Of Room)
    Return Me.ObjectContext.Rooms
End Function
```

But this doesn't appear to contain details about my buildings even though there is referencial integrity between Room.BuildingId and Building.Id.  Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To optimice performance related tables are not included by default in a query. You need to mark the tables that you wish to include in your query with [Include]. Furthermore you need to include the table in your query. Tim Heuer have reading a blogpost about how to do it:

http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2010/01/05/master-details-with-ria-services-and-includedresults.aspx

Comment: This alone didn't fix the problem.  I needed to also add the .Include("Building") function on the end of my ObjectContext.Rooms as was suggested by Shawn.  Any idea why this is needed?

Comment: Yes, you need the Include statement in your query. It's not always that you wish to include the related tables in your query (due to performance) and that is why you need to specify it in your query.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the buildings to be included, you need to use the `.Include("Building")` to your code:

```
Public Function GetRooms() As IQueryable(Of Room)
    Return Me.ObjectContext.Rooms.Include("Building")
End Function
```

Comment: This by iteself didn't fix the problem, but after decorating the Building property in the entity framework metadata file with the [Include] attribute, the values started appearing.  Do you know why I need to also include the [Include] attribute?  I like the idea of controlling this within code without any attribute decorations.

Comment: @Matt Ruwe - this is referred to as **eager loading**, which means in English: *When you go and fetch a Room, also go and fetch the associated Building*. As opposed to **lazy loading**, which means in English: *When you enumerate over a room and request the Building association, make a trip to the DB and get it*. I personally *disable lazy loading*, as i want total control of db round trips. Most developers do the same. Eager load what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Depending upon your requirements, you might want to consider returning a collection of "presentation model" objects (with each object containing information about both the room *and* the building), rather than entities.  You define a class in the server project, and populate a collection of objects of this type with the data from the entity model in a domain operation (which is passed to the client).  More information on doing so is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707347(VS.91).aspx.

Comment: I actually tried this method and it appeared to work, but when I wanted to save the information back to the database, it ended up creating new Room and Building objects instead of using the rows that were already in the database.

Comment: With this method, you have to provide your own updating logic in your domain service - you probably had some faulty logic in your LINQ to Entities query there.